# i have made a function to stem by data, but it gives error

Tags: python, pandas

```
def stem(text):
    y=[]
    
    for i in text.split():
        y.append(ps.stem(i))
        
    return " ".join(y)    

new_df['tags'].apply(stem())
```

```
error:stem() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
```

Comment: Typo? `.apply(stem)`

Answer (score 0):

try this code..

```
def stem(text):
    y=[]
    for i in text.split():
        y.append(ps.stem(i))
    return " ".join(y)

new_df['tags']=new_df['tags'].apply(stem)
```